# Django REST Framework - Issues with extending the user model using signals

Tags: python, django, rest

I am new to Django and want to extend my user model with OneToOne field (seems its mostly recommended), also I have a ManyToManyField which is mandatory. Below is my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Config_Table(models.Model):

    entity_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,default='')

class Profile(models.Model):

    "The Profile of a user with details are stored in this model."

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=11)

    # The default username is phone number (Ver. 1.0)

    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=11,default=user)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='../Static/1.jpeg')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    city = models.TextField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, default='')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Config_Table)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    USER_TYPES = (
        ('User','Normal User'),
        ('Leader','Tour Leader'),
        ('Admin','Administrator'),
    )
    user_type = models.TextField(choices=USER_TYPES, default='User')
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    official_docs = models.ImageField(default='../Static/1.jpeg')
    group_name = models.TextField(blank=True,default='')
    debit_card_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    MUSIC_CHOICES = (
        ('Rock','Rock Music'),
        ('Trad','Traditional Music'),
        ('Elec','Electronic Music'),
        ('Clas','Classical Music')
    )
    favorite_music = ArrayField(models.TextField(null=True,default=''),size=2)
```

Using shell, I can successfully create a user and assign a profile like below. The table "Config_table" has been populated with some initial data :

```
>>> user = User.objects.create_user(username='12345678900')
>>> test = Profile.objects.create(user=user,gender='M',city='NY',user_type='User',favorite_music=['Trad'])
>>> test.save
<bound method Model.save of <Profile: <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f9f98e8a080>>>
>>> test.interests.add('Ski')
>>> test.save
<bound method Model.save of <Profile: <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f9f98e8a080>>>
```

Now I want to make this a bit more easier for my views. So, what I've found [Here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone) and [Here](https://blog.khophi.co/extending-django-user-model-userprofile-like-a-pro/) I want to use post_save signals to create a create_user method which does all of the above with one line:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance,gender=instance.gender,city=instance.city,user_type=instance.user_type,
                               favorite_music=instance.favorite_music)
        Profile.interests.add(instance.interests)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

‌But when I try this like below. I get error :

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username='12345678900',gender='M',city='NY',interests='Ski',user_type='User',favorite_music=['Trad'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 150, in create_user
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 142, in _create_user
    user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 495, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwarg)
TypeError: 'gender' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

It seems that I'm missing something very obvious or very silly. Can someone please help? I am using Django 2.0.2 with Postgres 10.1 and Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Edit : The reason I want to do the above is to have the primary key of user and primary key of profile be the same, not like below. Below is a sample of what I got from the first answer (check "id" and "user" fields) :

```
>>> serial = ProfileSerializer(sample_profile,many=True)
>>> serial.data
[OrderedDict([('id', 13), ('first_name', ''), ('last_name', ''), ('phone_number', 'App.Profile.user'), ('avatar', '../Static/1.jpeg'), ('gender', 'M'), ('city', 'NY'), ('description', ''), ('date_of_birth', '2018-03-04'), ('user_type', 'User'), ('join_date', '2018-03-04T07:12:38.607959Z'), ('official_docs', '../Static/1.jpeg'), ('group_name', ''), ('debit_card_number', 0), ('favorite_music', ['Trad']), ('user', 18), ('interests', ['Ski'])])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that your **`post_save`** signal named **`create_user_profile`** is incorrect. The **`instance`** variable is a **`django.contrib.auth.models.User`** instance. It is the **`Profile`** model which has the **`gender`** attribute, not the **`django.contrib.auth.models.User`** instance. What you are trying to do is basically the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
print(user.gender)   # Does not exist
```

You have extended the `User` model by creating a `profile` underneath it, but you are trying to treat the `User` model as the `Profile` model, which it is not.

Personally, it seems to me like you would be better off creating your own custom user model by **[extending Django's `AbstractUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user)**. Profiles are good when you have a variety of different types of profiles, such as Facebook, Google, Employee, etc. which will have different attributes. Most of what I see that you have should be common enough to have on the custom user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    USER = 0
    LEADER = 1
    ADMIN = 2
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (USER, 'Normal User'),
        (LEADER, 'Tour Leader'),
        (ADMIN, 'Administrator'),
    )
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default=User.USER)
    # Your custom stuff here
```

I would suggest thinking of your database design prior to starting to code the User model. It will save you a lot of hassle in the future.

**[OFF TOPIC]:** Also, for what it is worth I want to mention that I see a ***major*** issue in your above example model. It appears you intend to store the debit card number in the database. Your application/organization would have to follow [PCI DSS (Payment Application Data Security Standard)](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/pa_dss.shtml). [It is not something that you want to take lightly](https://www.forbes.com/sites/sungardas/2014/07/01/7-critical-consequences-of-failing-pci-compliance/#2a7aee9114b9).

Comment: @micheal-b Here and there, I've seen people warning Django developers on inherting from AbstractBaseUser class. Also, I will lose the benefits of django authentication methods. I have my own data model designed beforehand, but during the course of django development, I saw many recommendations on extending the django usre model. So, I'll try this method and I'll update this page afterwards. Also, thanks for the tip on data security standard!

Comment: I will edit the headline, so it can be searchable for other people as well, who might have issues like me

Comment: @aLuViAn - the method that I provided is the `AbstractUser`, which keeps Django's authentication in place. It is the `AbstractBaseUser` class which you have to do more work for to keep authentication. :)